# Forfiles copy failes when using path variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, path, forfiles, pushd

I've got a problem with setting the path variable for the destination I want to copy files within a forfiles command to (`cmd /c copy @path destination`).
The code:

```
REM source folder location
set source=\\Path\TO\File\SOURCE\FOLDER
REM destination folder location
set set destination=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\
REM log_file location
set log_file=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\Logfile.txt

SET /a "copy_count+=0"
PUSHD  %source%
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
forfiles /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c copy @path 0x22%destination%0x22 & echo @file %date%, %time%>>0x22%log_file%0x22"
') do SET /a "copy_count"+=1
POPD
```

fails to copy the files in the designated directory but passing the Path directly into the command like:

```
.....
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
forfiles /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c copy @path E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\ & echo @file %date%, %time%>>0x22%log_file%0x22"
') do SET /a "copy_count"+=1
POPD
```

works.

How would I need to pass the variable correctly?

Edited to working code after comments from [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)

```
REM source folder location
set "source=\\Path\TO\File\SOURCE\FOLDER"
REM destination folder location
set "destination=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\"
REM log_file location
set "log_file=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\Logfile.txt"

SET /a "copy_count+=0"
PUSHD  %source%
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
forfiles /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c If @IsDir==FALSE copy @path %destination% & echo @file %date%, %time%>>%log_file%"
') do SET /a "copy_count"+=1
POPD
```

To clarify on [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) comment because I did not realize the time stamp stays the same throughout the whole process - Is this what your comment implied?

```
SET /a "copy_count+=0"
PUSHD  %source%
(for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
forfiles /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c If @IsDir==FALSE copy @path %destination% & echo @file %date%, %time%)>>%log_file%"
') do SET /a "copy_count"+=1
POPD
```

Comment: I'd start by changing `source=\\Path\TO\File\SOURCE\FOLDER`, to `Set "source=\\Path\TO\File\SOURCE\FOLDER"`, and `set set destination=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\ ` to `Set "destination=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER"`. I'd also advise that you use `Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE Copy…` to ensure that only files are identified too.

Comment: Also, have you considered just using `"Cmd /C Echo @Path"` in your `For` loop command, then `do` the `copy` etc. against `%%F`.

Comment: The problem is the trailing backslash that escapes the following quotation mark (encoded as `0x22`) in `forfiles`. Anyway, following up @Compo's suggestion of moving the copying out of `forfiles`: this would also allow you to redirect the whole `for /F` loop to the log file once rather than reopening it per iteration (put a pair of parentheses around the whole `for /F` loop and append the closing one with `>>"%log_file%"`). Regard that `%date%` and `%time%` currently expand to the same date and time values for each processed file…

Comment: To answer the new question, _which does not really achieve the additional efficiency, implied by my comment, and better explained by @aschipfl_, change `%date%, %time%` to `0x25DATE0x25, 0x25TIME0x25`.

Comment: thanks I just realized I I missed your second comment.

Comment: I have rolled back your previous edit @PeterS, which provided a solution within your question. If you wish to provide a solution, please provide one in the answer area instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example showing the methodology, I implied and suggested throughout my comments.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "source=\\Path\TO\File\SOURCE\FOLDER"
Set "destination=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER"
Set "log_file=E:\LOCAL\FOLDER\Logfile.txt"

PushD "%source%"

Set "copy_count=0"
(For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /D -2 /C ^
 "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @Path 0x25DATE0x25, 0x25TIME0x25"'
) Do Copy /Y %%G "%destination%" 1> NUL 2>&1 && Set /A copy_count+=1 & Echo %%~nxG %%H) 1> "%log_file%"

PopD
```